# Parsing the pattern “[noun] を [verb]、また [noun] のため”

Tags: parsing

I am not sure how to parse these two sentences, particularly the two highlighted clauses that fall under the same pattern:

> 治水とは　**洪水などの水害を防ぎ、また水運や農業用水の便のため**、河川の改良・保全を行うこと。
>
> 雨戸とは　窓や縁側などの外側に立てる戸。**風雨を防ぎ、また防犯のため**のもの。

(both dictionary definitions).

My attempt is:

（（洪水などの水害を防ぎ）、また（水運や農業用水の便の）ため）　(sentence 1)

（（風雨を防ぎ）、また（防犯の）ため） (sentence 2)?

Are these correct, or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "uninflected" form? Is "a の clause" an example of "uninflected"?

Comment: I think my terminology was a bit off there. Inflected/noninflected division only seem to apply to 自立語, but の is a 付属語. I will correct, thank you.

Comment: I think it was wrong of me to use terminology at all since the substance of my question lies elsewhere. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully grasp the question but I would understand that syntax to  mean that it is either for the purpose (ため) of A or (また) B (with or being used inclusively). Is that what you're trying to ask?

Comment: No need to overthink it, the question is as simple as "how do I parse these two sentences", focused on the 為 (bolded) clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sentence 1:

治水とは｛ [洪水などの水害を防ぎ] また [(水運や農業用水の便のため)河川の改良・保全を行う] ｝こと

The gist is 洪水とは…防ぎ…行うこと, i.e. こと is modified by 行う (adnominal), which is modified by 防ぎ (adverbial). Eventually 防ぎ can modify こと through 行う.

sentence 2:

（雨戸とは）[風雨を防ぎ] また [(防犯のための)もの]

This sentence is disproportional. Something like 雨風を防ぎ、また防犯に用するもの or 雨風を防ぐ、また防犯のためのもの will be better, though.